How to enable Chrome's password store prompt for a site?
Using Chrome I went to site. I logged in. On the prompt to store the password I clicked Never for this site. I reconsidered, and want to enable the password storage. How do I tell Chrome to ask me again the next time I try to log in?
I found this external question asking how do you undo 'never save' password?, yet one of its solution does not work:

Enter chrome://settings/passwords into your Chrome URL bar and
press enter. At this page bottom, you can find 'Never Saved'. Remove
the site you want Chrome to remember the password. And login that
website again. Chrome will ask you do you want it to remember again.

I don't see that option, and I realized that trying to access chrome://settings/passwords redirects to chrome://settings/passwords.
My Chrome Version is 129.0.6668.101


I was lacking Chrome's password manager.
chrome://password-manager/passwords
It asked me for an installation, I did, and now I see the relevant setting page. (I am not quite sure if that triggered the prompt, or another setting's page. If someone knows for sure, please leave a comment.)
The relevant page is at:
chrome://password-manager/settings
at the bottom with the headline: Declined sites and apps.
